# How convert a lif file to ascii file

Tags: converters

I need to convert a lif file (HP format) to an ascii file (IBM format). I know that I can do it in old versions of Windows using LifUtilities... Therefore, I do not have any computer near me like these. Anyone knows if I can do the conversion using Linux or other strategy?

Thanks in advance! Regards!

Comment: You can download a LIF/ASCII converter for PC from the [HP Museum:](http://www.hpmuseum.org/software/41uc.htm)

Comment: I know it, but it only works at Windows based at MSDOS... New versions of Windows do not work with LifUtilities

Comment: Never mind. I couldn't find anything else :(

Comment: I found on internet the LifUtilities for linux... on this link

http://www.hpcc.org/datafile/hpil/lif_utils.html

But I really do not know if it works...

Comment: Seems to work to me! Thanks for keeping us updated.